# bash loop file operations, passing temp names between commands

Tags: bash

After a day of cleaning 500M records in a dozen different files, I need some batch automation, please:

1. Have 100 or so files named HIST?????? (up to 6 characters after HIST)
2. I need to run four operations on each:

   ```
    iconv -f US-ASCII -t UTF-8 %filename% - c -o %tempname1%   
    iconv -f UTF-8 -t UTF-8 %tempname1% -c -o %tempname2%   
    cat %tempname2% | tr -d '\r' > %morepermanentname%  
    sudo python blah.py %morepermanentname%
   ```

Can anyone advise on how to create temporary names / pass them from line to line and loop this thing for all the HIST* files in the dir?

Does this look right?

```
for f in HIST*
do
    $temp1 = "temp1"
    $temp2 = "temp2"
    $semi = $f"perm"
    iconv -f US-ASCII -t UTF-8 "$f" -c -o "$temp1"
    iconv -f UTF-8 -t UTF-8 "$temp1" -c -o "$temp2"
    cat "$temp2" | tr -d '\r' > "$semi"
    sudo python blah.py "$semi"
 done
```

Please note that the iconv utf-8 to utf-8 with `-c` looks strange, but has caught some stuff.

Comment: Do you want DOS/Windows batch files? Or bash? (The `%var%` stuff makes me think batch.)

Comment: sorry, Emil, for the confusion -- most DEFINITELY bash, thanks!  Edited the title for clarity.  Will scrub out the inappropriate variable references once I know what is proper.

Comment: `temp1="temp1"` will work better; you should not use the `$` on assignment, and you never use spaces around the `=` sign. Note that the names `temp1` and `temp2` don't change from iteration to iteration, so you may as well move the assignments out of the loop.  You might add `trap "rm -f temp[12]; exit 1" 0 1 2 3 13 15` before the loop, and `trap 0` (or `trap 0 1 2 3 13 15`) after the loop, so any temporary files are removed if the script is interrupted (signals HUP, INT, QUIT, PIPE or TERM — plus general shell exit — that's the 0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the documented behaviour of `iconv` (read from standard input when no input file is given; write to standard output), you don't need the explicit intermediate files at all.

```
for file in HIST*
do
    semi="${file}perm"
    iconv -f US-ASCII -t UTF-8 -c "$file" |
    iconv -f UTF-8 -t UTF-8 -c |
    tr -d '\r' > "$semi"
    sudo python blah.py "$semi"
done
```

By quoting the file name variables when they're used, it also avoids issues if any of the file names contained spaces — not that it seems likely that will be a problem.

I'm curious — why on earth do you need root privileges for the `blah.py` script?  Is it copying the semi-permanent file to a privileged location or something?  Do you need to remove the semi-permanent file after the `sudo` command?

Comment: sudo needed as the output does indeed go to a privileged mount; semi-perm is left behind. This is cleaner -- thanks much!

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for `for`.

```
for f in HIST*
do
  ./process "$f"
done
```

Comment: thanks, Ignacio -- that helps me get started.  Assuming the ./process is then also a shell script.  How do I create a semi-permanent file name in process.sh that reflects the original file name?

Comment: [Parameter substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html) on `$1`.

Answer (score 1):

Editing your script:

```
for f in HIST*
do
    iconv -f US-ASCII -t UTF-8 "$f" -c -o "$f".tmp
    iconv -f UTF-8 -t UTF-8 "$f".tmp -c -o "$f".tmp2
    tr -d '\r' < "$f".tmp2 > "$f"perm
    sudo python blah.py "$f"perm
    rm "$f".tmp "$f".tmp2
done
```

You can obviously use the same `"$f"` in `tr` if you don't wish to retain the original copy instead of using `"$f"perm`.

- There should be no space between the `=` for variable assignment.
- The `$` sigil should not be used while assignment is being done.
- Quote variables.

Comment: Thanks, Jaypal, for the assist.  My addled brain has another 6 hours to go and you and Jonathan saved me some valuable time..